# 404 error trying to connect to redis database in a docker container

Tags: docker, redis, http-status-code-404

I am getting a `404` error when I am changing a user in an app built over a couple of docker containers. Here are my containers:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS         PORTS                                NAMES
ef575204dfc8   node:16.19-alpine     "node ./app/app.js -…"   2 days ago   Up 9 minutes   0.0.0.0:20000->13001/tcp             server-node-service-1
47efad61a584   redis:4.0.11-alpine   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 days ago   Up 9 minutes   6379/tcp, 0.0.0.0:20001->26379/tcp   server-node-redisdb-1
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"
services:
  redisdb:
    #name: nowce-developdb
    image: redis:4.0.11-alpine
    volumes:
     - ../database/redis/provider/${PROVIDER_ID}:/data
    ports:
     - "${REDIS_PORT}:26379"
    restart: unless-stopped

  service:
    image: node:16.19-alpine
    #restart: always
    working_dir: /home/node
    entrypoint: "node ./app/app.js --env production"
    mem_limit: "300M"
    memswap_limit: "1G"
    ports:
     - "${APP_PORT}:13001"
    volumes:
     - .:/home/node # modified here to take into account the new app path
    # - ./logs:/home/app/logs
    user: node
    links:
     - redisdb
    restart: unless-stopped

    environment:
     - NODE_ENV=production
     - AES=false
     - SERVICE_ROUTE=develop
     - PROVIDER_ID=${PROVIDER_ID}
     - PROVIDER_SUBDOMAIN=${PROVIDER_SUBDOMAIN}
     - PROVIDER_SUBDOMAIN_SUFFIX=${PROVIDER_SUBDOMAIN_SUFFIX}
     - ADMIN_USERNAME=${ADMIN_USERNAME}
     - ADMIN_EMAIL=${ADMIN_EMAIL}
     - ADMIN_PASSWORD=${ADMIN_PASSWORD}
     - PROVIDER_APIKEY=${PROVIDER_APIKEY}
     - INSTITUTION_CODE=${INSTITUTION_CODE}
     - CANDIDATE_URL=${CANDIDATE_URL}
     - CONTRIBUTOR_URL=${CONTRIBUTOR_URL}
```

I am changing the user within the console and I get a `404` error when trying to get to the url: `http://localhost:4200/NowCEDevelop/user/find/8bae6be6cd7e44288251983fe97767d4`

[404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AHkT.png)

I cannot understand why I am getting a `404` error. I assume it cannot connect to the redis database withing the docker container but I can't figure out why?

Comment: Nothing in your Compose setup seems to mention a port 4200 at all; where does that come from?  If you can successfully connect to something and get an HTTP 404 error (and not "connection refused" or similar) then it seems like your program is at least starting up and you're connecting to it, which suggests something at the HTTP-routing layer and not anything Docker-related.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: There are basically two projects, one front end and one back end. Part of this problem is that I don't know how the front end (which runs on localhost:4200) connects to the backend docker containers. How do I check that the front end can connect to the backend database?